# Move my windows 2003 vps server to my own location

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I am paying for a company to host my VPS. It's windows 2003 standard server. I'd like to host it myself at my office now that my internet account has been vastly upgraded.

Is there any way that from within the windows install that I can create a clone of the system and download it to my server. My host does not offer this type of feature/service.

I am running VirtualBox on my office server for a few other virtual machines and would love to add this paid one to the mix.

I have heard of people using ssh and tar'ing their Linux servers...but will that work if I install Cygwin on the win 2003 server?

Answer (score 0):

On win the fs-level clone won't work. You need to get a sector-by-sector copy of the hard disks. If you don't have physical access to the system, it will be hard. I tried this with an iscsi over vpn trick, but if you have luck, there are targeted tools for this job, too. With vss (volume shadow copy) can you trick your system to make a copy from himself to your local hard disk, but it needs luck, too.

Making a copy from a running systrm produces always, and sometimes really dirty filesystem errors, but with luck you could fix them with chkdsk. It were like if your system experienced a hard poweroff.

Second problem: if you have the checked/repaired clone system on your local disk, you need to boot it. The windows on it will feel not only the hard crash, but the total replacement of its hardware environment. Newer windowses can this survive with good chances, but win2k3 yet not. Altough it is not impossible, especially if you use the same motherboard and cpu type in your clone, as in the original was.

Good luck! And don't forget to pray :-)